# Get most recent media upload

Tags: php, images, uploads

Wordpress sites this as an example of how to get the thumbnail:

`<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $post_id, $size, $attr ); ?>`

I want to know how can I use the same basic function but just have it automatically get the latest media upload's ID number instead of having to specify the post_id.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think that you can use `get_the_post_thumbnail` function to get last uploaded media, but you can use `get_post` to get latest attachment and then [wp_get_attachment_image](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_image) to display images.

```
$attachments = get_posts( array(
    'post_type' => 'attachment',
    'posts_per_page' => 1,
    'post_status' => null,
    'post_mime_type' => 'image'
) );

foreach ( $attachments as $attachment ) {
    echo wp_get_attachment_image( $attachment->ID, 'thumbnail' );
}
```

Comment: The image is unattached to anything, so I was trying to get the most recently uploaded attachment / image and then go from there...

Comment: @cwd This snippet doesn't work for you?

Comment: oh, hmm, maybe it would. i guess i read your intentions for what it would do wrong. let me give it a try :)

Comment: The code is good, just needs one tweak `echo wp_get_attachment_image( $attachment->ID, 'thumbnail' );` - needs to include the `->ID` bit. thanks.